# Python Create new DF For student grade from 2 DF's , One contains StudentID and Marks Other contains Marks Series and Grade

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Please help with below Python Need updated DF to get each subject
        grade, From student & grade DF's , One contains StudentID and
        Marks Other contains Marks Series and Grade mapping.

```
df_student
StudentID Maths Science
1001    80    60       
2001    90    80

df_grade
Grade Subjects  Marks_range
0     A Maths  [81,90]
1     A Science  [81,90]
2     B Maths  [60,80]
3     B Science  [60,80]    

StudentID  Maths MathsGrade  Science ScienceGrade
1001    80   B   60   B     
2001    90   A   80   A
```

Please refer code here not able to format properly in description - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBrvo.png)
[image: Please refer code here not able to format properly in description]

Comment: Hi Satish, what have you tried so far, and what errors are you facing?

Comment: Hi , New to Python , Tried to Merge based on Series , but no luck

Comment: Your question is unreadable and incomprehensible. Please [edit] and format it better.

Comment: what you have done ? please format your question to be more readable.

Comment: HI All, not able to format , So attached as screenshot , please refer , thanks for looking in to this. As am new to Python , I just tried with Series comparision and merging

Comment: HI All, not able to format , So attached as screenshot , please refer , thanks for looking in to this. As am new to Python , I just tried with Series comparision and merging

Comment: How to format: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processing flow:

1. divide the grading categories into two columns
2. after splitting, join to the original DF
3. run a lookup function on the DF of the grade and add it to a new column
4. optimize the column names to the new DF and convert them to wide format.

```
df_grade['Marks_range'] = df_grade['Marks_range'].apply(lambda x: x[1:6])
df2 = pd.concat([df_grade[['Grade', 'Subjects']],df_grade['Marks_range'].str.split(',', expand=True)], axis=1)
df2 = df2.rename(columns={0:'Mark_min',1:'Mark_max'})
df2[['Mark_min','Mark_max']] = df2[['Mark_min','Mark_max']].astype(int)

def lookup_grade(x):
    subj = x['Subjects']
    score = x['value']
    match = (df2['Mark_min'] <= score) & (df2['Mark_max'] >= score)
    grade = df2[df2['Subjects'] == subj]['Grade'][match]
    return grade.values[0]

df_student['Grade'] = df_student[['Subjects','value']].apply(lambda x: lookup_grade(x), axis=1)
df = df_student.set_index(['StudentID','Subjects']).unstack()
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
df = df.rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
df.columns = ['StudentID', 'Maths', 'Science', 'MathsGrade', 'ScienceGrade']

df
    StudentID   Maths   Science MathsGrade  ScienceGrade
0   1001    80  60  B   B
1   2001    90  80  A   A
```

This answer has been a valuable experience for me. Thank you.